# x509certificate2 sign for jwt in .net core 2.1

Tags: .net, .net-core, jwt, rsa

I can make a JWT token using the JWT libraries, but for various reasons I'm have to make one by hand.  I have an X509Certificate2 object with both public and private keys in it - and I can find heaps of different code online that uses the privatekey out of that to sign - sometimes by casting it to rsacryptoprovider, sometimes by pulling it out as xml - I've found about ten different methods.

All of them work in .net framework.   *nothing* that I've tried works in net core 2.1 (even the ones that explicitly say they are for .net core).   The private key object is a RSACng, not a cryptoprovider - any attempt to call methods that get at the xml or the private properties say operation not supported - and the RsaCng doesn't have a sign method on it.

I have a bunch of bytes as a payload, and a fully populated X509certificate2 object (read from a .pfx file) - and all I want is to sign a string.  Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, that part is annoying. I ended up using BouncyCastle since it seemed to be the only way to make things easier. Be carefull when picking the nuget. There is a unoffical repack around which is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out to be easier than I thought - I was using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT - for some reason salesforce doesn't like the JWT it produces from the JWT functions (possibly because it adds heaps of other attributes) but anyway - I traced into the code of what it does - and you can use utilities from it - so if you create the JWT payload yourself - the following code produces a valid JWT:

```
    var unsigned = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(header) + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(payload);
    var x509 = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilename, certificatePassword);
    var signingCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(x509, "RS256");
    var signature  = JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(unsigned, signingCredentials);
    return unsigned + "." + signature;
```